# XmlSerializer, sgen.exe and generics

Tags: c#, .net, xml-serialization, sgen

I have a generic type:

```
public class Packet<T> where T : IContent
{
    private int id;
    public int Id { get { return this.id; } }

    private T content;
    public T Content { get { return this.content; } }
}
```

I want to deserialize/serialize instances of this type from/to XML. `IContent` is defined like that:

```
public interface IContent
{
    XmlSerializer Serializer{get;}
}
```

Basically, I would like the `Packet` to use the serializer provided by its content to serialize and deserialize its content member. This serializer is in fact an instance of a pre-compiled xml serializer generated by sgen.exe.

Is it possible without making `Packet<T>` implementing `IXmlSerializable`?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can implement a custom class directly with IXmlSerializable. 
For more information, see [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.ixmlserializable.aspx) article.

Comment: My point is I would like to avoid custom serialization using IXmlSerializable. (See last question line.)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Generic Type, it is not able to generate a pre-completed XmlSerializer.